# How to play audio from database with button in php and html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio, html5-audio

i tried to built my website with audio player inside. But i have problem when i combined song that load from database with play button. I want to make my play button change when it clicked and load song from database. I have codes like these :

**HTML and PHP**

```
<div id="playbtn">              
   <button id="play_btn" onclick="playPause()"></button>                    
      <?php
          $song= "SELECT mp3Lagu FROM folksong WHERE songtitle = 'Apuse'";
          $result = mysql_query($song);

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
              echo'
                 <audio id="listenlagu">
                 <source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['mp3Lagu'] ).'">
                 </audio>';
          }
      ?></div>
```

I used javascript to change the display button like these :

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
var audio, playbtn;
function initAudioPlayer(){
audio = new Audio();
//audio = document.getElementById('listenlagu');
//audio.src = "audio/Apuse.mp3";
audio.src = document.getElementById('listenlagu');  
audio.load();
audio.loop = true;
audio.play();

// Set object references
playbtn = document.getElementById("play_btn");

// Add Event Handling
playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);

// Functions
function playPause(){
    if(audio.paused){
        audio.play();
        playbtn.style.background = "url(images/pause70.png) no-repeat";
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        playbtn.style.background = "url(images/play70.png) no-repeat";
    }
}   
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
</script>
```

**but it's not working when i combined with javascript -_____-"**

Anyone know where the problems are ?
Can you help me to fix these ?

Comment: Are you sure you wish to send all the song mp3 embedded base64_encoded inside the web page? Isn't your page too large or slow? Instead, consider sending links and serve song per song on request.

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: check this line: audio.src = document.getElementById('listenlagu');  you are assigning the html element to the audio element's src property.  This will certainly throw an error.

Comment: @Arashsoft7 nope, but it's not load data

Comment: @morecchia808 hmm so how can i fill the js element with jquery to get my data ?

Comment: @paulH under 5 MB, base64_encode working in html and load my song from database no matter how large that size but i didn't want use html audio player. Nope, it's work normal on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the following (full code example below):

1. assign the src attribute to  audio.src
2. move your playPause function outside of the initAudioPlayer function
3. make your playPause function accept 2 parameters 1 - "audio" (the new Audio object) and 2 - playbtn (the button element), and have it return a function so that it can be used as a callback in the addEventListenter method

Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/bticzS?p=preview

```
    initAudioPlayer();

    function initAudioPlayer(){
      var audio = new Audio();
      var aContainer = document.getElementById('listenlagu');
      // assign the audio src
      audio.src = aContainer.querySelectorAll('source')[0].getAttribute('src');
      audio.load();
      audio.loop = true;
      audio.play();

      // Set object references
      var playbtn = document.getElementById("play_btn");

        // Add Event Handling
        playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause(audio, playbtn));
      }

      // Functions
      function playPause(audio, playbtn){
          return function () {
             if(audio.paused){
               audio.play();
               playbtn.style.background = "url(images/pause70.png) no-repeat";
             } else {
               audio.pause();
               playbtn.style.background = "url(images/play70.png) no-repeat";
             } 
          }
      }
```

Comment: also, it looks like you will have a problem with having many audio elements with the same id (<audio id="listenlagu">).  I would have the database generate a unique id for each element. and render it on the page.

Comment: still not working. the button didn't call the data from query

Comment: what the function of array 0 / [0] ?@morecchia808

Comment: @GinaYunitaRachma - can you show us your html as it is rendered in the browser?  The code I posted in my answer works well.  I will post a plnkr shortly.

Comment: sorry for late reply. your code was running well but how can i change <source src="http://s1download-universal-soundbank.com/mp3/sounds/2433.mp3"> with query from database ? because i want put my song from database.